# Cannot redirect on submit

Tags: php, forms, redirect, header

I have a basic form and I am trying to redirect to a page different from the index page on submit. I can only get this:

```
 header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/thanks.php");
```

to work when I place it above

```
 <!doctype html>
```

But this will not work in IE and I receive HTML5 validation errors.

Here is my code:
At the top of the page:

```
   <?php
  include("functions/contactfunctions.php"); 



   ?>
```

further down:

```
  <?php
    if($_POST['submitted'] == "contactus")
    {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
            if(!$firstname)
    $error = "Please enter your first name.";
    else
    if(!$lastname)
    $error = "Please enter your last name.";
    else
    if(!$email)
    $error = "Please enter a valid email.";
    else
    if(!$message)
    $error = "Please enter your message.";
    else
    if(!$location)
    $error = "Please tell us where you're from.";


    }
  ?>

    <?php
       if($_POST['submitted'])
       {
      ContactMessage($firstname, $lastname, $email, $message, $location);
        header("Location:http://www.mywebsite.com/thanks.php");
       exit;
    }

 ?>
```

Here is contact functions.php:

```
 <?php 
 include_once("databasefunctions.php");

 $contactsdbtable = "contacts";

 function GetHeaders()
 {
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    $headers .= "To: {$firstname} <{$email}>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: My Site <noreply@mysite.com>' . "\r\n";
    return $headers;
 }
 function ContactMessage($firstname, $lastname, $email, $message, $location)
 {
global $contactsdbtable;
openDatabase();
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);
$location = mysql_real_escape_string($location);

$result = QuickQuery("INSERT INTO {$contactsdbtable}(firstname, lastname, email,         message, location) 
                      VALUES('{$firstname}', '{$lastname}', '{$email}', '{$message}',  '{$location}')");

if($result)
   {
    $headers = GetHeaders();
    $message = "\"Thank you for contacting us blah blah. We will be        answering your website inquiry post haste.\"<br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Best Regards,<br />
    <br />
    Us
    ";
    mail($email, "RE: Website Inquiry", $message, $headers);
    mail("myemail@blank.com", "Website Inquiry", "{$firstname}, {$email}, has sent a web design inquiry", $headers);

     }
   }


 ?>
```

I have also tried adding 
     
on the index page and contactfunctions.php to no avail. On submit, I get redirected back to index.php which is the action on the form.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If header(); didn't redirect the page, then it means the form isn't submitting as it should.
Instead of checking $_POST['submitted'] I advise you check all inputs in the form.

```
if($_POST['email']&&$_POST['message']/* And so on... */){
   echo "echo something here so you know it ACTUALLY HAS been submitted.";
}
```

TIP: When using header(); make sure you use ob_start(); and ob_flush(); like this:

```
//Start of script
ob_start();

//Now header(); will work efficiently here inside your functions...

//End of script
ob_flush();
```

Comment: I added this- in combination with removing the white spaces seems to be working now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces before the opening `<?php`. You can't have *any* content before you send headers, and that includes whitespace.

Comment: I'm sorry; not sure what you mean by spaces? Spaces from what to what? and the top <?php on which page, the index or contactfunctions?

Comment: @user1505573: On both pages; the two spaces right before `<?php`. Take them out.

Comment: which <?php there are many-- I have indented them here so the code will show up, but the top <?php on both pages are not indented in the actual code

Comment: @user1505573: The first `<?php` on each page. Also, you need to combine the two PHP blocks, because there's whitespace between them and you send the header in the second one. The `header`s must come before *any* output.

Comment: It works if I place the header before the doctype but I get this error on w3 validation, "comments seen before doctype. Internet explorer will go into the quirks mode."

Comment: @user1505573: Are you pasting PHP into the validator? That doesn't work.

Comment: yes. So placing the header before the doctype will not cause any problems in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces and word wrap before

```
<?php
```

Even white spaces are informations sent to the navigator, so that's not anymore in the header.

EDIT : Answer already given.